# Error Bundling Puma M2 Macbook Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, arm, rbenv

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails application, but I get an error every time I try to run my server using the following command:

```
bundle exec puma -C ./config/puma.rb
```

the error logs:

```
106454000-10645c000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/objspace.bundle
10645c000-106460000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/objspace.bundle
106460000-106464000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/objspace.bundle
106464000-106470000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/objspace.bundle
106480000-106484000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/io/console.bundle
106484000-106488000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/io/console.bundle
106488000-10648c000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/io/console.bundle
10648c000-106490000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/io/console.bundle
106490000-1064e8000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libssl.3.dylib
1064e8000-1064f4000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libssl.3.dylib
1064f4000-1064f8000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libssl.3.dylib
1064f8000-10651c000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libssl.3.dylib
10651c000-106524000 r-x /usr/lib/libffi-trampolines.dylib
106524000-10652c000 r-- /usr/lib/libffi-trampolines.dylib
10652c000-106530000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/pty.bundle
106530000-106534000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/pty.bundle
106534000-106538000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/pty.bundle
106538000-10653c000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/pty.bundle
10653c000-106540000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debug_inspector-1.1.0/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
106540000-106544000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debug_inspector-1.1.0/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
106544000-106548000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debug_inspector-1.1.0/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
106548000-10654c000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debug_inspector-1.1.0/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
10654c000-106550000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.2/lib/thin_parser.bundle
106550000-106554000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.2/lib/thin_parser.bundle
106554000-106558000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.2/lib/thin_parser.bundle
106558000-10655c000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.2/lib/thin_parser.bundle
10655c000-106574000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
106574000-106578000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
106578000-10657c000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
10657c000-10659c000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
10659c000-1065b4000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/curb-1.0.5/lib/curb_core.bundle
1065b4000-1065b8000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/curb-1.0.5/lib/curb_core.bundle
1065b8000-1065bc000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/curb-1.0.5/lib/curb_core.bundle
1065bc000-1065d8000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/curb-1.0.5/lib/curb_core.bundle
1065e0000-106660000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.21.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
106660000-10666c000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.21.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
10666c000-106670000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.21.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
106670000-1066a4000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.21.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
1066a4000-1066bc000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
1066bc000-1066c0000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
1066c0000-1066c4000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
1066c4000-1066d8000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
1066d8000-1066dc000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stackprof-0.2.25/lib/stackprof/stackprof.bundle
1066dc000-1066e0000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stackprof-0.2.25/lib/stackprof/stackprof.bundle
1066e0000-1066e4000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stackprof-0.2.25/lib/stackprof/stackprof.bundle
1066e4000-1066e8000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stackprof-0.2.25/lib/stackprof/stackprof.bundle
1066e8000-1066ec000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stackprof-0.2.25/lib/stackprof/stackprof.bundle
1066fc000-10670c000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redcarpet-3.6.0/lib/redcarpet.bundle
10670c000-106710000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redcarpet-3.6.0/lib/redcarpet.bundle
106710000-106714000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redcarpet-3.6.0/lib/redcarpet.bundle
106714000-106720000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redcarpet-3.6.0/lib/redcarpet.bundle
106720000-106724000 r-x /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS
106724000-106728000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS
106728000-10672c000 rw- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS
10672c000-106734000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOLocatePlugin_macOS
106740000-1069d0000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.15.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.7/nokogiri.bundle
1069d0000-1069e0000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.15.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.7/nokogiri.bundle
1069e0000-106a7c000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.15.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.7/nokogiri.bundle
106a7c000-106a84000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/byebug.bundle
106a84000-106a88000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/byebug.bundle
106a88000-106a8c000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/byebug.bundle
106a8c000-106a94000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/byebug.bundle
106a94000-106a9c000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/readline.bundle
106a9c000-106aa0000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/readline.bundle
106aa0000-106aa4000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/readline.bundle
106aa4000-106aac000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/readline.bundle
106aac000-106ab0000 r-x /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS
106ab0000-106ab4000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS
106ab4000-106ab8000 rw- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS
106ab8000-106ac0000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppSSOConfigPlugin_macOS
106ac0000-106af0000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/ripper.bundle
106af0000-106af4000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/ripper.bundle
106af4000-106af8000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/ripper.bundle
106af8000-106b04000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/ripper.bundle
106b38000-106bd0000 r-x /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gpgme-2.0.22/lib/gpgme_n.bundle
106bd0000-106bd4000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gpgme-2.0.22/lib/gpgme_n.bundle
106bd4000-106bd8000 rw- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gpgme-2.0.22/lib/gpgme_n.bundle
106bd8000-106bf4000 r-- /Users/emiliocontreras/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gpgme-2.0.22/lib/gpgme_n.bundle
106c00000-106d00000 rw- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/heimdalodpac.bundle/Contents/MacOS/heimdalodpac
106d00000-106d04000 r-x /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/heimdalodpac.bundle/Contents/MacOS/heimdalodpac
106d04000-106d08000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/heimdalodpac.bundle/Contents/MacOS/heimdalodpac
106d08000-106d0c000 rw- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/heimdalodpac.bundle/Contents/MacOS/heimdalodpac
106d0c000-106d14000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/heimdalodpac.bundle/Contents/MacOS/heimdalodpac
106d14000-106d18000 r-x /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/Reachability.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Reachability
106d18000-106d1c000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/Reachability.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Reachability
106d1c000-106d20000 rw- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/Reachability.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Reachability
106d20000-106d28000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/Reachability.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Reachability
106d28000-106d2c000 r-x /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/SCKerberosConfig.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SCKerberosConfig
106d2c000-106d30000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/SCKerberosConfig.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SCKerberosConfig
106d30000-106d34000 rw- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/SCKerberosConfig.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SCKerberosConfig
106d34000-106d3c000 r-- /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/SCKerberosConfig.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SCKerberosConfig
106d50000-106d7c000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/readline/8.2.1/lib/libreadline.8.2.dylib
106d7c000-106d80000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/readline/8.2.1/lib/libreadline.8.2.dylib
106d80000-106d88000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/readline/8.2.1/lib/libreadline.8.2.dylib
106d88000-106da0000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/readline/8.2.1/lib/libreadline.8.2.dylib
106dc8000-107004000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib
107004000-10705c000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib
10705c000-107060000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib
107060000-107114000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib
107114000-107154000 rw-
107200000-107300000 rw-
107300000-107400000 rw-
107400000-107500000 rw-
107500000-107600000 rw-
107600000-107700000 rw-
107700000-107800000 rw-
[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
```

I use Rbenv with ruby 2.7.5 on a M2 chip (ARM). I haven't installed any package like brew, rbenv, nvm using the arch x86_64 flag, and my application worked perfectly until last week, and I haven't been able to fix this problem.

Comment: Has it been fixed? I am getting the same issue when running rails 6 app with ruby 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

The log is missing the error. It only shows the tail of the call stack.
So it's a bit guessing.

I would try to

- update homebrew (brew update, what probably broke your installation)
- reinstall ruby with rbenv
- prune and reinstall your bundle

Answer (score -1):

My strong advice is to use docker to do development.  Then you are not at the mercy of the host system libs, updates (or lack thereof), etc.

https://github.com/rails/docked looks like a reasonable option - but there are many.